# how to fill input value onclick via xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, xpath-2.0

i want to fill input value with click function, like this

```
<script>
function inputfillclick() {
document.getElementById('inputidx').value="KuchBhi"
}
</script>
 
 <input type="text" id="inputidx" name="inputidx" />
 <button class="button" onclick="inputfillclick()">Fill Now</button>
```

but the problem is i want do this on other page where the input field does not have id, i want to do this via xpath, is there any way?

```
<input maxlength="140" step="" enterkeyhint="done" autocomplete="off" type="password" class="uni-input-input">
```

and xpath is

```
//input[@type='password']
```

full xpath

```
/html/body/uni-app/uni-page/uni-page-wrapper/uni-page-body/uni-view/uni-view/uni-view[3]/uni-view[2]/uni-view[2]/uni-input/div/input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the document.evaluate() method to select the input element using its XPath expression and then set its value using the value property.

```
  function inputfillclick() {
  var xpath = "//input[@type='password']";
  var inputElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (inputElement) {
    inputElement.value = "KuchBhi";
  } else {
    console.log("Input element not found.");
  }
}
```

In this code, the `document.evaluate()` method selects the first input element with a `type` attribute set to '`password`' using the given XPath expression. If such an element is found, its value property is set to '`KuchBhi`'. If no input element is found, the code logs a message to the console.

You can call the `inputfillclick()` function using a button or any other event handler on the page where you want to fill the input field.

Comment: yeah that script is working brother but there is one problem, this script replace input value but not fully, the submit button is disabled, but if i try to type manually or paste in input field then the submit button enabled